# Instant nausea when boarding aircraft

Tags: nausea, travel, motion-sickness, aviation

Every time I am about to board a jet plane (your standard Boeing 737 for example) I am hit with instant debilitating nausea while inside the boarding ramp. (That enclosure that connects the aircraft with the terminal.) I believe it has something to do with the air inside the plane since it only hits once I can smell that distinct odor that the inside of jet aircraft have.

This extreme unpleasantness lasts for about 20 minutes upon boarding and gradually decreases. For the rest of the flight I am fine although occasionally I will get small hints of it.

I have flown single engine prop aircraft (Cessna 172) and this never happens around them.

If anyone knows what this is and how I can stop it I would be eternally grateful. It has made traveling by plane extremely unpleasant.

Comment: http://umu.diva-portal.org/smash/record.jsf?pid=diva2%3A464846&dswid=8224

Comment: @CountIblis haha I'm not the only one. :D

Comment: Jet fuel is very similar to kerosene. Do you get the same nausea around a burning kerosene lamp?

Comment: I feel as though this is bordering the line between educational and professional medical advice. That being said I'd try what Jack said. Kerosene, and other fuels, can cause nausea for people when it's too concentrated in the air. As long as you aren't also experiencing chest pains and/or stomach pains you should be fine. The smell may also be from the smell of the cleaner they use to clean the aircraft. Though don't quote me on that.

Comment: @JackSwayzeSr I'm not sure where I could go to be around a kerosene lamp but I've certainly never had the same feeling around anything over than jet aircraft.

Comment: @FrankyG The feeling of nausea gradually grows as I walk down the boarding ramp but it only really his me when I walk through the aircraft door. So yeah maybe it's the cleaner...never thought about that.

Comment: In that case I'd definitely think it's whatever they use to clean/freshen the aircraft. If it was the fuel you'd probably have to be near, if not, right next to the engines (or wherever the fuel smell would be most powerful from an aircraft, I'm no expert) for that to have an effect on you. To me going through the door doesn't make me think fuel is the problem. If they are using ammonia or something similiar to clean I wouldn't be surprised that it gives you issues as it's a pretty powerful smell even to those that can tolerate it. Still I'd see a doctor about it, at best our advice is limited

Comment: So this same thing happens to me. I get very sick until we are well after take off. And I also can’t ride a city bus because of how nauseated I get. One time a bus driver told me I had “industrial allergies” basically it’s the smell of the gasoline etc that makes me sick. I’ve always now wondered if that’s the same thing making me sick on the plane. Cuz once the doors close and we start to fly I start to kinda feel better. But let’s face it, that takes a while, by the time you actually take off and get up to the elevation and are flying for a while before all the fuel “sickness” starts to wear

Comment: @Alexandra interesting. For what it’s worth, the smell of gasoline (I.e. what you use for your car) is very pleasant to me. Diesel is somewhat neutral smelling to me and doesn’t produce nausea.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds as though you're developing a conditioned response or allergy to some smell of the aircraft insides. Insecticides are used in some international flights but this is prior to disembarkation, and should have cleared by the time you embark. If it's linked to a particular airline, it may be the air freshener they use, and as your flight proceeds, the internal air recirculation systems scrub the air of it. So, you could ask the airlines if they all use a particular product.

Perhaps you could try some nasal filters  with activated charcoal to scrub the air for you to see if it helps in that first 20 minutes.

Comment: It's with all airlines. The effect is no different. I'll do some research on the air fresheners they use. Thanks.